# Resource not exist in current context in razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have `Resources.resx` file created in my webapp `wwwroot/Resources` folder.

When i try to use it in razor view as `@Resources.SomeValue` i got an error

```
The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context
```

When i move file to `wwwroot` folder, i can use resource.

I have tried to use `@Resources/Resources.SomeValue`, but i got same error

Is there a way to move this file somewhere away from root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web.config file in your Views folder, add a namespace to the namespaces node for your Resource folder. Should look something like this:

`<add namespace="wwwroot.Resources" />`

This should allow you access to that folder in your views. You may have to close and reopen the view to get Intellisense.